# BenQ GL2055 display shifted off screen

Tags: windows-10, display, vga, lcd

I recently picked up a BenQ GL2055 at a yard sale. The monitor displays computers BIOS's fine as well as Hirens Boot CD, but when plugged into my PC the image is shifted about 3" to the left and 1" down. I have already tried solutions from other articles about this issue such as power cycling, resulotion changes, connecting to another machine. The monitor only appears to have this issue when displaying something from an OS like Linux or windows 10.

Now the way the monitor is setup is as follows

- DVI - VGA adapter from R7 370 card to VGA cable
- VGA cable to monitor
- Monitor is secondary monitor for a windows 10 machine that has Update 1703

I was going to post the link to the BenQ support page but I don't have the reputation for it.

Picures of monitor as well as software setup
[Win10 Software Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7D0s.png)
[Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afQai.jpg)